# if-then-else condition in apache virtual host

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have an Apache virtual host defined for `https ://sb.domain1.com` and I need to do a different action depending on the IP address which calls the virtual host. If the call comes from `172.16.xxx.yyy` then i need to redirect to `http ://sb.domain2.com` else i need to redirect to `http ://sb.domain1.com`.

That is I don't know how to translate the following lines (which come from /etc/http/conf.d/ssl.conf file):

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.254.68:443>
    ServerName sb.domain1.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/STAR.ca-bundle
    SSLEngine on
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 600
    if IP = 172.16.xxx.yyy
        then 
           Redirect to http ://sb.domain2.com
        else
           ProxyPass / http ://sb.domain1.com/
           ProxyPassReverse / http ://sb.domain1.com/
        else
    ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/sb/ssl_error_log 86400"
    CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/sb/ssl_access_log 86400" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

can you suggest me translating the above directives?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^172\.16\.
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://sb.domain2.com/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and then just

```
ProxyPass / http://sb.domain1.com/
ProxyPassReverse / http://sb.domain1.com/
```

After all, if you match the IP, you will be redirected, so no other requests will be made here.  Everyone else will then be proxied.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, mrjink.
As I am not very into Rewriting, i would like to know what this line means:
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://sb.domain2.com/$1 [L,QSA]
If my IP is in 172.16.xxx.yyy and I typed https://sb.domain1.com/pippo.txt i will be redirected to http://sb.domain2.come/pippo.txt
?
Thank you very much indeed

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  If that's not what you want, you can remove the $1 and QSA from the RewriteRule, and you'll be redirected to the plain domain (without pippo.txt).  Also, please refer to the excellent wiki pages at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Rewrite .